# flush functions are deleting my html temporarily

Tags: php, html, flush

Notice: Yes I did ask this question once before but it got immediatly marked as a duplicate although the linked duplicate had almost nothing to do with my question.

I wrote a php script that is executing my application to download images from the web. And in order to show some kind of progress being made on my website I used flush to echo out some information for the User. Here is my code:

```
      echo '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Starting to gather data!</li>';
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      $url = $unsplash;
      $cmd = $unsplash . ' - ' . $amount;
      exec($cmd);
      echo '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Gathering Data Completed</li>';
      ob_end_flush();
```

The code I am using does work without any problem (besides this one) so there is no error there!

Unfortunately every kind of HTML content I write under my php script is being deleted for the duration of the script executing (which sometimes can take up to 5 minutes). But immediately after the script finished the Content beneath reappears. Another thing worth mentioning is, that when I open DevTools in Chrome (F12) during the scipt is being executed is shows nothing!

Am I doing something wrong ? I cant seem to figure it out...

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, exactly what you mean by "*being deleted*", but what you need to take into consideration is that output buffering can happen at multiple levels (PHP, Web Server, Client UA, etc..).

If the output from your script does not appear right away, it's likely that you have [`output_buffering`](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) enabled at a higher level (i.e. in your php.ini or other loaded configuration). Because output buffers cascade, they flush at each level. Check your [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo) and if you see a value other than `0` for `output_buffering`, then you need to edit the php.ini file showing in `phpinfo()` under *Loaded Configuration* (near the top) and change that value to `0` then restart your parent PHP process.

Another thing to consider is that some browsers won't render some HTML block-level elements like `<div>`, `<ul>`, etc... until they are closed. The content may have arrived at the client, but some browsers don't process the rendering of the content until the block level element is complete. So a better way to test that the output is being received on the client end without these variable nuances might be to send a text/plain Content-type header from your PHP to get the HTML rendering stuff out of the way. `header('Content-type: text/plain')`, if turning off the output_buffering in PHP still doesn't give you the desired result.

Comment: I mean that, any kind of html content I place below my this php script is gone for the time the script is running - like there is nothing. And then after the script finishes it reappears. I checked my phpinfo() and the value for output_buffering is 4096 - is that normal ? Edit: I think we can count out your second option as I clearly can see the <h1>Hello</h1> before it vanishes for the time the code is running! :)

Comment: "*reappears*" would imply that it had at one point already appeared. That language is ambiguous. Yes, in most default php.ini files, you would see `output_buffering` turned on. If you wish to turn it off (as you clearly do) then just set it to `0` as clearly stated in the answer in order to get the desired behavior you're after.